# Sphere in the differential geometry

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

For example, a sphere is obtained by rotating at the picture.

How to get asurface patch (parametrization) $\sigma$?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small *caveat*: the image of the curve $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$, $u\mapsto \gamma(u)=(\sin u,0,\cos u)$ is just a circle of radius $1$ and center $(0,0,0)$ in the $x$-$z$ plane in $\mathbb R^3$.

Let us move to the unit sphere.
To parametrize the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ we need 2 coordinates (longitude and latitude); let us call them $u$ and $v$. Any point $p=p(u,v)$ on the sphere can be written as

$$p=(\sin u\cos v, \sin u\sin v, \cos u), $$

with $u\in [0,\pi]$ and $v\in[0,2\pi)$. In other words, our parametrization is 
$$ \sigma: [0,\pi]\times[0,2\pi)\rightarrow\mathbb R^3,~~ (u,v)\mapsto\sigma(u,v)=(\sin u\cos v, \sin u\sin v, \cos u). $$

Comment: You are wonderful!! I asked this question for two days. All questions are closed. I ll read it right now. Thanks a lot:)